# Как правильно привязать команду к Datagridtextcolumn wpf mvvm c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, bindingsource

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="AVBusiness.View.Documents.IncomeUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AVBusiness.View.Documents"
         xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:AVBusiness.CT" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AVBusiness.View" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" xmlns:models="clr-namespace:AVBusiness.Models" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=view:IncomeDetailViewModel}"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="674" d:DesignWidth="859">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <convert:ComboInConvert x:Key="Cv"></convert:ComboInConvert>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="White" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="36*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="13*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="85"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="34"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Background="#FF101653" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <Label FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#DDFFFFFF" FontFamily="Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold" Margin="50 10 10 10">Приходы</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Код</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">№</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Статус</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Дата накладной</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Дата офрмления</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Курс</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Комментарий</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Оформил</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBox x:Name="tbCode"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbNumber"></TextBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbSt"></ComboBox>
        <DatePicker x:Name="dpInc"></DatePicker>
        <DatePicker x:Name="dpUpd"></DatePicker>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Width="150" x:Name="tbMoney"/>
            <ComboBox Width="170" x:Name="cbCurrency"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbComment"></TextBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbUser"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Наименование</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Владелец</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Страна</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Юр.адрес</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Физ.адрес</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Телефон</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Номер договора</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.7">Договор до</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Банк</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">БИК</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">Рас. счёт</Label>
        <Label FontSize="12.75">УНП</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="tbName"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbOwner"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbCountry"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbUrAddress"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbFizAddress"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbPhone"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbNumdog"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbDateDog"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="tbBank"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbBic"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbPayment"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbYHH"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="3" Height="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <!--<DataGrid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="4" MinHeight="400" Height="Auto">-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgIncome" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_Source}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows= "False" CellEditEnding="dgIncome_CellEditEnding">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Edit">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding Edit}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedRow}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="№ п/п" x:Name="dgTCName" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Партия" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgNumParty" Binding="{Binding NumParty}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Секция" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding BranchId }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Код" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ProductId }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наименование" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Кол-во" x:Name="dgQty" Binding="{Binding Qty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    EditingElementStyle="{Binding Edit}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Edit">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding Edit}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedRow}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="С/с" Binding="{Binding PriceC }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Надбавка розница" Binding="{Binding PriceCallowance }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="∑ розница" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding SumPriceCr }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Надбавка опт"  Binding="{Binding WholeSaleSurcharge }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="∑ опт"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding SumWprice }"/>
                <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ставка НДС"  x:Name="dgcbTax"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Percent"
                                        SelectedValuePath="IdTax"
                                        >
               -->
                <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SourceCB}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>-->
                <!--
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SourceCB}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.
                        
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="СтавкаНДС">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding _Source}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding IdTax}"
                                      
                                       
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Percent"
                                      SelectedValuePath="IdTax" 
                                      
                                     />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Налог %" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTax, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Percent"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TaxId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Taxx, Mode=TwoWay}"/>-->
                <!--непонятно как делать бинд в комбобоксу-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сумма НДС(розница)" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TaxSumR }"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сумма НДС(опт)"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TaxSumR }"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена реализации(розница)" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TotalPriceR }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена реализации(опт)"   IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TotalPriceW }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена р-ции($ розница)" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding TotalPriceCurR }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена р-ции($ опт)" IsReadOnly="True"   Binding="{Binding TotalPriceCurW }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сертификат" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding NumSert }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ШК" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Barcode }"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="НаПродаже" Binding="{Binding Prod, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" FontSize="10" Padding="0 0 0 0" Width="240" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 0 0" MinHeight="20" Height="30" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 0 0" MinWidth="120" Width="120">
            <TabItem.Header>Основное</TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 0">
                    <Button Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click" >Товар</Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Edit}" Cursor="Hand">Контрагент</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 0 0" MinHeight="20" Height="30" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 0 0" MinWidth="120" Width="120">
            <TabItem.Header >Дополнительно</TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button>Печать</Button>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbReady">
                        <UIElement.RenderTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform/>
                        </UIElement.RenderTransform> Готовность
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>

            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Cursor="Hand"
                Command="{Binding Edit}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}">НазадН</Button>
        <Button>Назад</Button>
        <TextBlock Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="tbNum">0</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="tbMinNum"></TextBlock>
        <Button>Вперёд</Button>
        <Button>ВперёдВ</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Как правильно привязать к Datagridtextcolumn команду на изменение данных после выхода из ячейки Datagrid. Команда Edit рабочая, проверил на кнопке, пробую сделать привязку по триггеру - не работает.

Comment: Чтобы сохранить данные, надо коммит для строки выполнить. Вообще interaction triggers это жестокий костыль проброса событий в команды, что при нормальном знании wpf и mvvm в принципе не требуется.

Comment: `Label` - устаревшее наследие из Winforms, используйте `TextBlock`. Попытался разобраться в разметке, непонятно что к чему должно привязано быть. Нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример, где нет ничего лишнего.

Comment: Что непонятного в моем вопросе? При чем здесь разметка? Покажите просто как правильно бинды на DataGridColumnText поставить.

Comment: Данные в ячейке привязываются к свойству, так? При изменении свойства можно выполнить любой код прямо из сеттера. Зачем здесь команды - загадка.